# how to set first and last tick mark and x axis value in jfree bar chart x-axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

im using jfree chart in my application. For my application i need to mark only first and last value of the x axis and also tick mark.
I've tried

```
String Male1 = "First";
        String Male2 = "sec";
        String Female1 = "0-4";
        String Female2 = "5-18";
        String Female3 = "19-45";
        String Female4 = "46-64";
        String Female5 = "65+";
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(202, Male1, Female1);
        dataset.addValue(130, Male2, Female1);
        dataset.addValue(216, Male1, Female2);
        dataset.addValue(0, Male2, Female2);
        dataset.addValue(248, Male1, Female3);
        dataset.addValue(458, Male2, Female3);
        dataset.addValue(517, Male1, Female4);
        dataset.addValue(623, Male2, Female4);
        dataset.addValue(1481, Male1, Female5);
        dataset.addValue(680, Male2, Female5);        
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "", "", "", dataset,
                PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, false);
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
        plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.2f));
        plot.setAxisOffset(RectangleInsets.ZERO_INSETS);        

        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setAxisLinePaint(Color.decode("#C1C1C1"));
        rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(true);
        rangeAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
        rangeAxis.setTickMarkOutsideLength(0f);

        final CategoryAxis categoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        categoryAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
        categoryAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
        BarRenderer br = new BarRenderer();
        br.setItemMargin(0.03);
        br.setShadowVisible(false);
        br.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        br.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#999999"));
        br.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.decode("#CCCCCC"));        

        chart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(br);
        chart.removeLegend();
        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("/media/hari/668ea9a3-d26c-4896-a2f0-756dfb532756/jfreeBarchart.png"), chart, 280, 180);
            System.out.println("=====Bar chart=====");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For the above code im **getting**

[image]

But my **expectation** is

[image]

Please help me to get the expected chart in jfree bar chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to only display two ticks (0 and 1500) and add a noticeable inside tick mark to both.

To display only two ticks you can call [`setTickUnit`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setTickUnit%28org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit%29) with the appropriate size argument. This size will be used by the axis object to generate the visible ticks.

To add tick marks on the inside you can call [`setTickMarkInsideLength`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#getTickMarkInsideLength%28%29).

So adding these three lines should do the trick:

```
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1500));
rangeAxis.setTickMarksVisible(true); 
rangeAxis.setTickMarkInsideLength(3f);
```